# How to make a dual boot system for Ubuntu and Windows?

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot

How can one install dual boot system for running Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 for a computer that has only Ubuntu 18.04 installed? Is there any other way than copy important files from Ubuntu to USB stick, remove Ubuntu, install Windows, install Ubuntu alongside with Windows, and copy files from memory stick to Ubuntu?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu I don't know if this fully applies to Windows 10, you should also read guides for the more common way with Windows installed first. If you have to make space on your disk you should backup your data in case something goes wrong, so copying to USB stick is a good idea.

Comment: I know this does not answer your question and may not be possible but the safest and easiest ways to set up a dual boot are to use separate disks for each OS. Disconnect the Ubuntu hard drive, connect the fresh hard drive ready for Windows, install it. Reconnect all your drives and in the BIOS select the boot priority to the Ubuntu disk and grub's `os-prober` should be able to detect the Windows disk and you can select between the operating systems either at the BIOS or GRUB level.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to maintain from the old to new Ubuntu install but generally all of *your* data is in /home & backing it up/restoring will bring back your configuration.

That said you will need to same software installed so for instance if you had steam on the old box you'll need to install it on the new one before your games will work...but you won't have to re-download them and your saves etc will be there.

Once you have a backup you should be able to install Windows first and then Ubuntu with no issues. You could run "dpkg --list" to get all of the packages from the old Ubuntu box if that helps.